# How to serialize tree hierarchical data in XML format

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am using C# with VS 2012. I have a collection of Employee objects like `List<Employee> employees`.  Each Employee object has properties of EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, and ParentId. The depth of the tree data is unlimited. I'd like to serialize that "employees" collection in XML format as follows:

```
<employees>
   <employee id="1">
     <firstName>aaa</firstName>
     <lastName>bbb</lastName>
     <parentId/>
        <children>
           <employee id="2">
               <firstName>ccc</firstName>
               <lastName>ddd</lastName>
               <parentId>1</parentId>
               <children>
                  <employee id="3">
                       <firstName>eee</firstName>
                       <lastName>fff</lastName>
                        <parentId>2</parentId>
                       <children/>
                    </employee>
                    <employee id="4">
                       <firstName>ggg</firstName>
                       <lastName>hhh</lastName>
                       <parentId>2</parentId>
                       <children/>
                    </employee>
               </children>
            </employee>
            <employee id="5">
                       <firstName>kkk</firstName>
                       <lastName>lll</lastName>
                       <parentId>1</parentId>
                       <children>
                            <employee id="6">
                                 <firstName>mmm</firstName>
                                 <lastName>nnn</lastName>
                                  <parentId>5</parentId>
                                  <children/>
                              </employee>
                       </children>
            </employee>
        </children>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

And the sample contents of `List<Employee>employees` collection look like:

```
EmployeeId  FirstName   LastName    ParentId
1             aaa       bbb         null
2             ccc       ddd         1
5             kkk       lll         1
3             eee       fff         2
4             ggg       hhh         2
6             mmm       nnn         5
```

Comment: Where does Children come from?

Comment: @svick, a child record is one who has non-null ParentId property as in collection of List<Employee>.